# existence of the logarithmic norm (matrix measure)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces

Let $(\mathbb R^n,\|.\|)$ be a normed Euclidean space. Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a matrix . The induced matrix norm is defined as $\|A\|_*:=\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|$.

The logarithmic norm of a matrix A is defined as the right derivative of the induce matrix norm at I in the direction of the matrix A. In other words:

$\mu(A):= \lim_{h\to 0^+} \dfrac{ \|I+hA\|_* -1 }h. $

Since norms can be in general non-differentiable (e.g, l1), what is the proof that this limit exists always? also, does the proof generalize to the case when $\|.\|$ is a semi-norm?

I would highly appreciate a proof sketch or a reference that discusses this issue.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\|\cdot\|_\ast$ is an induced norm, $\|cI\|_\ast=c$ for every non-negative real number $c$. Therefore, for any $0<h<k$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\|I+hA\|_\ast -1}{h}
&=\left\|\left(\frac{1}{h}-\frac{1}{k}\right)I+\frac{1}{k}I+A\right\|_\ast - \frac{1}{h}\\
&\le\left\|\frac{1}{k}I+A\right\|_\ast 
+\left\|\left(\frac{1}{h}-\frac{1}{k}\right)I\right\|_\ast
- \frac{1}{h}\\
&=\left\|\frac{1}{k}I+A\right\|_\ast 
- \frac{1}{k}\\
&=\frac{\|I+kA\|_\ast -1}{k}.
\end{aligned}
$$
That is, when $h>0$, the function $h\mapsto\frac{\|I+hA\|_\ast -1}{h}$ is increasing. It is also bounded below by $-\|A\|_\ast$. Hence $\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\|I+hA\|_\ast -1}{h}$ exists.

When $\|\cdot\|$ is a semi-norm, you need to be careful about the existence of $\|\cdot\|_\ast$ here, as $\{x\in\mathbb R^n:\|x\|=1\}$ is not necessarily compact or non-empty. Anyway, as the argument above does not depend on the positive definiteness of $\|\cdot\|$, the same conclusion holds when $\|\cdot\|$ is a semi-norm, *provided that $\|I\|_\ast,\,\|A\|_\ast$ and $\|I+hA\|_\ast$ exist for all $h>0$*.

Comment: for the semi-norm, if we assume that is a Minkowski functional also, are we guaranteed the existence of the limit?

Comment: @M.A That depends on the set associated with the functional. If the set is arbitrary, the answer is still no. E.g. let $K\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ be the set consisting of the two vertical lines $x=1$ and $x=-1$. For each $\mathbf v=(x,y)^T$, define $\|\mathbf v\|=\inf\{r\in\mathbb R:\,r>0,\,\mathbf v\in rK\}=|x|$. Then every unit vector $\mathbf v$ is in the form of $(\pm1,y)^T$ where $y$ is arbitrary. So, when $M=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$ with $b\ne0$, $\|M\mathbf v\|=|\pm a+by|$ is unbounded. Hence $\|M\|_\ast$ does not exist. In particular, $\|I+hA\|_\ast$ does not exist when $h>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the definition of the logarithmic norm is a directional derivative. More precisely it is a right Gateaux differential. Since every function satisfying the **vector norm axioms** is left- and right-Gateaux differentiable, the logarithmic norm limit exists whenever $A$ **is bounded**. (In fact, existence only depends on **convexity**, so the log norm limit exists also in the operator seminorm case.)

In the answer above, with $\|v\| = |x|$, the norm is constructed so that $M$ is unbounded. This is not really a counterexample. For all bounded linear operators we have $\mu(A) \leq \|A\|$, no matter how the induced operator norm is defined. The "counterexample" only shows that if an operator is unbounded, then the G-differential may also be unbounded. (The converse is not true: there are unbounded linear operators with finite logarithmic norms, in Hilbert space.)